# Tab as radio select and clear checkboxes on tab change foundation 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, zurb-foundation

Im trying to make tabs with showing options. like:

showing options

- Show for all
- Hide for all
- Show for specific
- Hide for specific

these are the tabs and also these are radio select buttons

(looks like radio button but on check switchs to it's tab content)

And every tab content has it's own checkbox select list (except "show for all" and "Hide for all")

But, on showing option change inner content of all other tabs needs to be unchecked

*Foundation 6, Jquery, CSS*

Comment: Can you post your HTML?

Comment: @dom_ahdigital , Thank you for response, but I've solved this issue last night, evening I'll post full answer (what it used for, and how it works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The aim of this question is to use it a form, so you can select item showing options, and according to your select there will be available items for showing.

**FORM.HTML**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <ul class="clear-list">
            <li>
                <label class="select-label">
                    <input name="module_show_option" type="radio" value="all" checked>
                    Show on all pages
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="select-label">
                    <input name="module_show_option" type="radio" value="none">
                    Don't show on any page
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="select-label">
                    <input name="module_show_option" type="radio" value="selected">
                    Show only on selected
                </label>
            </li>
            <li>
                <label class="select-label">
                    <input name="module_show_option" type="radio" value="except">
                    Show on all except selected
                </label>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("input[name=module_show_option]:radio").click(function () { // attack a click event on all radio buttons with name 'radiogroup'

                    if ($(this).val() == 'all') {
                        $("input[name=module_menu_item_id]:checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    }  else if ($(this).val() == 'none') {
                        $("input[name=module_menu_item_id]:checkbox").attr("disabled", "disabled");
                    } else if ($(this).val() == 'selected') { //check which radio button is clicked
                        $("input[name=module_menu_item_id]:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
                    } else if ($(this).val() == 'except') { //check which radio button is clicked
                        $("input[name=module_menu_item_id]:checkbox").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="medium-12 columns">
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_menu_item_id" value="1">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_menu_item_id" value="2">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_menu_item_id" value="3">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_menu_item_id" value="4">
        </label>
        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="module_menu_item_id" value="4">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see I've rejected idea of tabbing content, instead I used disabling input fields, so it will disable checked items from pasting in POST body, and also it will preserve them from losing while you can chenge your decision